# Smart div, move div right if at the left end of screen and vice versa

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div that contains information about a video that is only displayed when the video div container is hovered on. 8 videos fit one row before the next row of 8 videos. the first and last video of the row has a problem where the div displayed on hover is out of the screen, as seen in the example image.[image]

I would like to get the result below:
[image]

The result I would like is similar to the hover description box seen on this movie website [yesmovies](http://yesmovies.to/yes.html)

**mov.html**

```
 //first instance
<div id="move-item">//on hover shows middle div
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div class="mov_item">
<div class="middle">//hidden with css
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
</div>
</div>

</div>

//second instance
<div id="move-item">//on hover shows middle div
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div class="mov_item">
<div class="middle">//hidden with css
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
</div>
</div>

</div>
.................
//eight instance
<div id="move-item">//on hover shows middle div
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div class="mov_item">
<div class="middle">//hidden with css
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
</div>
</div>

</div>
```

**css**

```
     .mov_item {

     position: relative;
     float: left;
     margin-left: 40px;

        }
     #item{
     width: calc(100% - 4px);
             }
     .mov_item a {
      font-size: 16px; 
       display: inline-block;
       margin-bottom: 8px;
       width: calc(50% - 4px);


          }

     .mov_item a:nth-of-type(2n) {
      margin-right: 0;
              }

      @media screen and (min-width: 50em) {
       .mov_item a {
       width: calc(25% - 6px);
                }

         .mov_item a:nth-of-type(2n) {
         margin-right: 8px;
                }

     .mov_item a:nth-of-type(4n) {
        margin-right: 0;
                   }
                        }
            .mov_item{

            margin-bottom: 30px;
           }
     /********description box wrapper**********/
       .middle {
        transition: .5s ease;
         visibility: hidden;
          position: absolute;
        display: block;
       transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

     display: inline-grid;
     border-top: solid 1px #ff1111;


         }

      .mov_item:hover .image {
      opacity: 0.2;
              }

     .mov_item:hover .middle {
      visibility: visible;
      z-index: 3;
              }
     .text1 {
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 12px;
       padding: 16px 32px;
       font-weight: bold;
       margin-top: -60px;
       margin-left: -20px;
       width: 180px;
       font-weight: bolder;
            }

   .play_mid{
         transition: .5s ease;
          opacity: 0;
         position: absolute;
         transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
         z-index: 1;
         margin-top: -85px;
         margin-left: 60px;
         text-decoration: none;
                }

        .mov_item:hover .play_mid {
        opacity: 1;

             }

        .mov_item:hover .text1{

         opacity: 0;
                       }
```

how can I achieve the designed result on the second image or similar to the link

Comment: The **mov.php** you posted is useless, just show us the actual output (With proper indentation), who can understand anything from that mess?

Comment: maybe you searched for [Popper.js](https://popper.js.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see, you are using nth-child so you just need right formula for every first element and every last element.
You can use for example`:nth-child(8n)` for every 8th element in row a different css. So if it is 8th "box of description" just change the location of that box. I do not see the problem.

I agree with Alon Eitan... php needs edit if you want more accurate answer and for the sake of regulations and users of this website to keep questions and answers clear.

**Edit**

As our conversation below expands lets explain something. My mistake... there is no such thing as `:nth-of-class`, and `:nth-of-child` or `:nth-of-type` works on all children down, so the dirty solution to this is just to override the children css to normal.

I will use `:nth-of-type` instead of `:nth-child` in example below:

```
#container div:nth-of-type(1){ // our div here is #move-item
  background: yellow;
  color: red;
}
#container div div {
  background: white!important;
  color: black!important;
}
```

We change first element on first level of divs and then we normalize second level

and we finish with this fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/w1Lqwzqu/5/
to play with

Comment: when i try something like `.middle :nth-child(1){
    margin-left:80px;  
}` for example only the 1st div shoud be affected but instead all divs are affected.

Comment: all the divs are in a loop, could that be whats causing them to all be affected?

Comment: yes, nth-child should be use on row of that elements that you will hover to show the box. To make it more generic, for row that contains 8 elements, every first would be 1,9,17,25... so I think `nth-child(8n+1)` would be correct. For n=0  its 1, for n=1 its 9, for n=2 its 17. 
If I answered your question please approve, or there is other related problem ?

Comment: @chris94
change your php to html(output from your browser) and clear indentation, because right now i cant relate to your code

Comment: i have updated mov.php to html. The problem is that `.middle :nth-child(1)` affects all children

Comment: @chris94
Why you use it on .middle ?

Comment: @chris94
 nth-child works on its parent so you should use `.move-item:nth-child(){}`
oh my bad, i thought it will work like :nth-of-class(), but obviously something like this doesnt exist, sorry

Comment: i have changed it to `.move-item:nth-child(1){}` all children are still affected. i have 8 instances of the the parent and child divs. inside the parent and child divs there are more divs.

Comment: i have updated the html to give you a better understanding of what i'm working with

Comment: so the only way is to override the children class to normal state ? very dirty solution but i cant think about other right now

Comment: how do you do that?

Comment: @chris94
i think thats it, but dirty. `div > div` scopes all second levels of children

Comment: it makes all the divs white for me

Comment: @chris94 

`<div class="container"><div id="move-item">blabla<div class="next">first child of move item</div></div></div>`. Based on my example blabla will be red on yellow background and `.next` will be black on white. Am i wrong ?

Comment: on your first fiddle  jsfiddle.net/w1Lqwzqu/1  is it possible to make only before first hi yellow and ignore before second hi?

Comment: @chris94 i come up with something like this
http://jsfiddle.net/w1Lqwzqu/5/
play with it